# How can I get a subview to recognized gestures when one of its superviews has clipsToBounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I have a subview that I have gestures attached to. 1 of it's superviews has ClipsToBounds = YES but it's own superview does not. My gestures are getting ignored. How can I prevent this.

Here's the view hierarchy:

-- view (clipsToBounds = YES) frame: {0,0,240,240}
---- view (clipsToBounds = NO) frame: (0,0,480, 240}
------ view (gestures added to this view do not get recognized outsize of 240x240 and inside 480x240)

Comment: There's nothing about subviews that precludes gesture recognizers. Nor does the presence or absence of clipToBounds affect it. I just took an existing "image dragging" UIPanGestureRecognizer and moved the images into a non-clipped view, which itself was in a clipped view, and it works fine. Looks like you can't start the gesture outside of the view's superview (probably a non-issue), but either than that, it works fine. Perhaps you (a) tell us what kind of gesture recognizer you have; (b) which of these various views you're putting you recognizer on; and (c) share some code.

Comment: Totally agree with Robert at least provide us what is the view you are attaching the gesture recognizer and some code snippet.